# How do I get android studio to work?

Tags: android-studio

I have a million things wrong with android studio. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it twice and nothing works.

I can't create a java class. I can't run a tester. I can't connect an emulator. When I tried to connect an emulator it said I had a fault in apk and my sdk weren't installed. But they were so I tried to uninstall them and reinstall them but only the platform sdk would reinstall the other would always get to the end before it quit the install saying there was not internet connection.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get android studio to work?

Answer (score 0):

What computer OS are you running?
have you installed all the java packages?

Comment: Windows 10. Downloaded the latest sdk